# Conditional rendering and warning when using propTypes validation

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that expects children on input. PropTypes are set as following:

```
static propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element).isRequired
};
```

However I receive warning when inline conditional turns false, i.e:

```
{isLoggedIn && <div>You are logged in</div>}
```

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children[0]` of type `boolean` supplied to `WelcomeComponent`, expected a single ReactElement.

Documentation does not really help.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Have you tried explicitly returning `null`? `{isLoggedIn && <div>You are logged in</div> || null}`

Comment: @Tholle null works. I wonder if documentation is wrong or propTypes validation rule.

Comment: @Throlle I tried this but it gives me an error `Cannot read property 'type' of null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how the `&&` operator works. If the first expression is falsy, the result of its evaluation will be the return value of the operator. You can read about it in details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators.

In your case it will return `false` when the user is not logged in, and you still expect to get a valid React element, which it does not satisfy.

You can see the logic that `PropTypes` use to check whether the received props are OK (for the element check) right here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L378. In your case the `typeof false === 'object'` will fail. Then https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/types/ReactPropTypes.js#L252 this method will print the warning.

Comment: I know how boolean logic works. Please see documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical-ampamp-operator

Comment: @Andy Edited the answer, hope it's more clear why the warning appears now.

Comment: But documentation states:

It works because in JavaScript, true && expression always evaluates to expression, and false && expression always evaluates to false.

Therefore, if the condition is true, the element right after && will appear in the output. If it is false, React will ignore and skip it.

Comment: It states that these (`false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `true`) are valid children, but just aren't rendered (for convenience of conditional rendering): https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored

Comment: How can I achieve the same, do I need to use a custom PropType validator? `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element)` throws error apparently.

Comment: Use `PropTypes.node.isRequired` which is described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#react.proptypes).

Comment: So if you don't want to pass null inside a prop ternary condition, what about defining your propTypes like this, for example? `oneOfType([bool, ...]`, is this a good or bad approach? I'm not really sure how some style guides would cover this.